# Java: Initializing error for temperature Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: java

I keep getting an **initializing error for `fdeg`.** Im trying just to show a table that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit.

my code:

```
public class TempTable
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      double cdeg;
      double fdeg;

        System.out.println("Fahrenheit" +"\t" + "Celsius");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

      for ( cdeg = 0;  fdeg <= 20;  cdeg++) 
        {
                fdeg = 1.8 * cdeg + 32;

            System.out.printf( "    %3d C = %5.1f F\n", cdeg, fdeg );
       }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Telling us the error might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
for (cdeg = 0; fdeg <= 20; cdeg++)
```

You're making a declaration that `fdeg` is a defined value, and is less than or equal to 20.  However, you only *declare* `fdeg`, but you do not set any initial value to it.  You cannot use a variable that is not defined - hence the error:

> variable `fdeg` might not have been initialized

What you likely intended to do was go from `cdeg = 0` to `cdeg = 20`.  Simply change the variable in your loop.

```
for (cdeg = 0; cdeg <= 20; cdeg++)
```

Comment: Yeah but when i do that it gives me these errors:


**Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Doubleat java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:3999)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2709)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2661)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2433)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
 at TempTable.main(TempTable.java:25)**

Comment: Not the problem I was out to solve.  Although I'm willing to bet, if you mirrored the way that `fdeg` is getting printed out using `printf`, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
fdeg <= 20
```

to

```
cdeg <= 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you have `fdeg <= 20` which can't be verified if `fdeg` is not initialized. That is, at the very first loop run it tries to check it but can't because `fdeg` is undefined.

Just put `double fdeg = 0;` and it will fix it. But I have a feeling you really mean `cdeg <= 20` though.